# Google App Engine Permissions Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment

I'm trying to deploy an app on Google App Engine and I get this error 
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\Users\broschke/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens'

I don't know what it means. Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: check out [ask].  what research have you done so far?

Comment: You should show what you have done or steps you've taken that lead you to this error from your side, so that we can better understand you and help you.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have no permissions to access `C:\Users\broschke/.appcfg_oauth2_tokens`. Check if it's there and then check the file permissions.